# Memory occupied by reference to a variable in cpp

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Declaring pointer:

int a;
int *x=&a;

x occupies 8 bytes of memory

Likewise if we declare a reference to a variable:

int a;
int &x =a;

How much memory does the the reference to a occupy?

Comment: Where does it say `x` as a pointer occupies 8? Or that it has to occupy any memory at all as a reference?

Comment: @StoryTeller: 1) presumably in the compiler documentation, as it's Implementation Defined. 2) Not.

Comment: @MSalters - The OP didn't specify a compiler. They only specified the language tags. Which I think means we can say "the standard doesn't define it, and you should not make implicit assumptions".

Comment: @StoryTeller if you check sizeof(x) in ubuntu in gnu c compiler you will get 8 bytes

Answer (score 0):

That's undefined. Not as in Undefined Behavior, but the question simply doesn't have an answer.

Comment: Well, it could have an answer *when using a particular compiler on a particular piece of code*. It doesn't have an answer in a general sense. I'd say "unspecified" fits the C++ terminology better.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: Actually, we see in real compilers that it varies depending on the exact usage. Calling it "unspecified" suggests there's a compiler-dependent single value that's just unknown.